# Exclude variables in regression based on causality-criteria in SAS

Tags: sas, regression

I have done my best to search the web for an answer to my question, but haven't been able to find any. Maybe I'm not asking in the right way, or maybe my problem can't be solved... Well, here goes nothing!

When running a regression in SAS, it is possible to do backward or forward selection and thereby eliminating all insignificant variables, which is great, but just because the p-value of variable is ≤ 0.05, that doesn't necessarily mean that the result is correct.

**E.g.**, I run a regression in SAS with the dependent variable being numbers of deaths due to illness and the independent variable being number of doctors. The result is significant with p ≤ 0.05, but the coefficient says, that as the number of doctors rises, the number of deaths also goes up. This would probably be the result of a spurious regression, but the causality is wrong, but SAS is only a computer, and doesn't know which way, the causality would go. (Of course it could also be true, that more doctors=more deaths due to some other factor, but let us ignore that for now).

My question is: Is it possible to make a regression and then tell SAS, that it must do backward/forward elimination, but according to some rules I set, it also has to exclude variables that don't meet these rules? E.g. if deaths goes up, as the number of doctors increase, exclude the variable number of doctors? And what would that

I really hope, that someone can help me, because I am running a regression for many different years with more than 50 variables, and it would be great if I didn't have to go through all results myself.

Thanks :)

Comment: It is possible to augment SAS to build a system that applies additional rules. I.e. p<0.05 when # of variables > 100, but p < 0.04 when # of variables <= 100 using the macro language to create a %do loop and continue to run it while some conditions are still met.

However, this may be a bit of a time commitment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible or recommended. As mentioned, SAS is a computer and can't know which regression results are spurious. What if more doctors = more medical procedures = more death? Obviously you need to apply expert opinion to each situation but the above scenario is just as plausible.

You also mention 'share of docs' which isn't the actual number if I'm correct? So it may also be an artifact of how this metric is calculated.

If you have a specific set of rules you want to exclude that may be possible. But you have to first define all those rules and have a level of certainty regarding them.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't clear enough in my question. I want to set up some rules, but I don't know how. I will correct my question Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think there's a statistically valid way to do what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify unusual parameter selection criteria you could always roll your own machine learning by brute force: partition the data, run different regression models over all the partitions in macro loops, and use something like `AIC` to select the best model.

However, unless you are a machine learning expert it's probably best to start with something like `proc glmselect`.

SAS can do both forward selection and backwards elimination in the `glmselect` procedure, e.g.:

```
proc gmlselect data=...;
 model ... / select=forward;
 ...
```

It would also be possible to combine both approaches - i.e. run several iterations of `proc glmselect` in macro loops, each with different model specifications, and then choose the best result.